# How to only get the name of files which changes are more than whitespaces?

Tags: git, diff

I try to get the name of files which have changes are more than whitespaces. (In another word, I don't want the files with only whitespaces changes be listed.)

I tried "git diff --name-only -w" it doesn't work. It lists all the changed files including the whitespaces only ones.

Answer (score 8):

To solve this issue, I wrote a script to do it. Hope it useful to others.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GIT_REPO_ROOT=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
# cd ${GIT_REPO_ROOT}

for f in `git diff --name-only`;
do 
    MY_DIFF=`git diff -w ${GIT_REPO_ROOT}/${f}`
    if [[ ! ${MY_DIFF} == "" ]];
    then
        echo ${GIT_REPO_ROOT}/${f}
    fi
done
```

This script reduce the result from 88 files ('git diff --name-only') to 8 files.

Comment: You might need to be careful here if you filenames have spaces in them, since `for` will typically iterate over each space-delimited word in diff and not each line. You could work around this by setting `IFS` to newline, or using `git diff --name-only | while read -r f; do ... done` instead of `for`

Comment: does exactly what I wanted it to do.  Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

Add ignore-blank-lines option. Try

```
git diff --name-only -w --ignore-blank-lines
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Still got the same amount of files as 'git diff'

Comment: What is your core.whitespace config? Type "git config core.whitespace"

Comment: my config is **trailing-space,space-before-tab**

Answer (score 2):

Use this one-liner:

```
git diff --name-only -z |
xargs -P`nproc` -0 -n1 bash -c '[[ $(git diff -w "$0") = "" ]] || echo "$0"'
```

- Safely handles names with spaces or special characters.
- Parallelizes calls to `git diff` for a quicker result. (Remove `` -P`nproc` `` if the result order is important to you.)

Comment: Well, it's a potential one-liner.  The `|` makes what comes after continue the same command, just I just put it like this to make it more readable, but it's still one command only.